# the value does not change recursion during the stack unwinding

Tags: algorithm, recursion, linked-list, stack, stack-unwinding

```
void reverseLinkedList(Node* &head) 
{
    if (head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr) 
    {
        return ;
    }

    Node* Rest = head->next;

    reverseLinkedList(Rest);
    head->next->next = head; 
    head->next = nullptr;   
    head = Rest;
}



int main() 
{
    Node* h = nullptr;

    Create(h, 4);//create linked-list with N nodes
    reverseLinkedList(h);
    Print(h);
}
```

according to the debugging, the ***Rest*** variable still has the same value during the stack unwinding. does it is supposed to be changed every call stack? but it still has the same value in each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the Rest variable still has the same value during the stack unwinding.

This is expected.

When the last recursive call occurs, the local variable `Rest` is initialised  to the tail node, which *after* that call returns is assigned to the pass-by-reference `head` variable. This `head` reference is the `Rest` variable of the caller, so also that caller's local `Rest` now points to the tail. And so the unwinding continues where each `head = Rest` copies that tail reference to the caller's `Rest` variable (because `head` is a pass-by-reference parameter).

That `head = Rest` assignment really is like the "portal" back to the caller. And so each caller gets their own `Rest` variable to point to the original tail node, which is now the head of the reversed list.